# What is the difference between a runner, a floater, and a tear drop?

Tags: basketball, terminology

In the regular season, a lot of scoring techniques are used to maintain a good ppg average. Throughout all of the games I have watched, I have seed a lot of different layups, and their use. Many players use a floater to effectively score points, but on other plays, a seemingly  identical layup is named differently. This happens to  the tear drop, the floater, and the runner. What is the difference between these three, and what are key factors that distinguish them from the others?

Answer (score 1):

The runner, floater, and teardrop all really refer to the same type of shot. It's primarily a move used by shorter players to make shots when they are going right up into taller defenders.

As long as the ball is shot at a high arc to get over the outstretched arm of the taller defender, then the shot can be called either one of the above three terms.